# Confused with Swift Where Clause.

Tags: swift

So i'm still learning but i'm struggling to understand a certain part of this code:

```
  case let newSquare where newSquare > finalSquare:
    // diceRoll will move us beyond the final square, so roll again
    continue gameLoop
```

Why does newSquare end up being 27, 28 and 29 each time I run through the loop?

Shouldn't newSquare be 0 each time? I've tried printing out newSquare in the loop and each time it turns out to be 27, 28, 29.

Here is the full code for reference:

```
let finalSquare = 25
var board = [Int](count: finalSquare + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
board[03] = +08; board[06] = +11; board[09] = +09; board[10] = +02
board[14] = -10; board[19] = -11; board[22] = -02; board[24] = -08
var square = 0
var diceRoll = 0

gameLoop: while square != finalSquare {
    if ++diceRoll == 7 { diceRoll = 1 }
    switch square + diceRoll {
    case finalSquare:
        // diceRoll will move us to the final square, so the game is over
        break gameLoop

    case let newSquare where newSquare > finalSquare:
        // diceRoll will move us beyond the final square, so roll again
        continue gameLoop

    default:
        // this is a valid move, so find out its effect
        square += diceRoll
        square += board[square]
    }
}
print("Game over!")
```

Sorry i'm sure it's simple but I'm not quite getting it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct is actually not just mere:

```
case let newSquare where newSquare > finalSquare: // ...
```

... but:

```
switch square + diceRoll {
// ...
case let newSquare where newSquare > finalSquare: // ...
```

`switch` statement evaluates `(square + diceRoll)` and compares it to all specified cases in the order.  First one to be `true` wins and assumes the control of execution.

In this particular example, `case let newSquare where newSquare > finalSquare` will "win" every time when `(square + diceRoll) > finalSquare`, which in terms of the game-logic means that we run over the board limit.  In-place constant `newSquare` is of no real use here (i.e. we do not use its value anyhow) and is introduced just to be able to use `where` statement of switch-case.

Temporary constant `newSquare` gets initialised via so called [*value binding*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID133):

> A `switch` case can bind the value or values it matches to temporary constants, for use in the body of the case. This is known as *value binding*, because the values are “bound” to temporary constants within the case’s body.

---

BTW, alternative way of saying almost the same thing as in the example would be:

```
switch square + diceRoll {
// ...
case finalSquare..<Int.max: // ...
```

... as preceding `case finalSquare` will take care of the option that we end up precisely on the final square, while range `finalSquare..<Int.max` will get to be evaluated only afterwards, therefore will only trigger if `(square + diceRoll)` is greater than `finalSquare`.

Comment: Ahh okay thanks for the reply. I think understand now, how come newSquare takes on the assumed values of (square + diceRoll) though?

Comment: It's because the sequence of values that `diceRoll` assumes is deterministic.  If you just add a `print` statement right at the beginning of the loop, you will see it progressing like {1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...}.  And it happens that with the board as it is, it will overrun it 3 times with the values you see.

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood me. I get why the values iterate, what I wanted to know was why does square + diceRoll = newSquare. I assume this what happens when you create a new variable/constant within a switch statement?

Comment: Ah. This is so called _value binding_.  See the edits to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `newSquare` becomes the value (because of `let`) of `square + diceRoll` when (`where`) the condition `newSquare > finalSquare` is true.

Since `finalSquare` is 25, then only when `square + diceRoll` will be over 25, this case will execute.